# Rebalancing table with average value

Tags: math

Looking for algorithm which will resolve my problem, i.e.

1. Having a table with values: [6, 2, 3, 1]
2. Get an average value per slice: 12/4 = 3
3. Re-balance values in slice, i.e. I should get formulas something like: 1) 0, 2) 6-1, 3) 0, 4) 5-2. I.e. from highest value deduct amount need's for average. As result I will need to get slice [3, 3, 3, 3]

Thanks

Comment: What happens if there is two highest values? for instance with [5, 2, 4, 1] or even [4, 4, 2, 2].

Comment: @Cadeyrn for [4, 4, 2, 2] - avg is 3, so it should give like 1) -1 (4-1 ==3), 2) -1 (4-1==3), 3) 0 (we moved it from 1), 4) 0 (we moved it from 2)

Comment: Anyway I think I resolved it, by sorting and double loop from bottom to top and top to bottom and gradually calculating values. The only I am strangling now is to code logic when I need to deduct from multiple places